# Bootstrap 4.1 modal resizing on input focus in IE11

Tags: bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

I am experiencing an dialog resizing / shifting in Bootstrap 4.1 only when being viewed in Internet Explorer 11 (only tested in IE 11).

The issue manifests when focusing an input in the modal.

This can be seen in the following gif taken from the [Bootstrap 4.1 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) page for modals

I can't seem to find anything regarding this behavior.

It can be *fixed* by setting focus on a field when the dialog opens, however some dialogs might not have any elements focus when being opened.

Are there any recommended workaround or fix for this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the CSS-Class `form-control`. When you change `display: block` to `display: inline` then the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by explicitly setting the `outline` property for any affected elements to `0`.  For example, adding the following css solved the problem for me:

```
.form-control {
    outline: 0;
}

button, button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```